# What is the source of this sloka which is prohibiting keeping pets at home?

Tags: identification-request, caste-system, animals, shloka

I got the following sloka in Sri Sri Sitarama-Kathamrita, a collection of gospels of Sri Sitaramdas Omkarnath, by Kinkar Brahmanda (page 27):

> kukkuta-swana-marjaran poshayanti dinatrayam/ 
> iha janmani sudratwam mriah swaa chaavijaayate//
>
> meaning :
>
> If a twice-born keeps cock, dog or cat as pet for three consecutive
>   days, he becomes sudra in this birth and born as dog in the next
>   birth.

Could someone provide the source of this sloka?

Comment: Vishnu purana have similar verse with similar meaning but not exact.

Comment: @Triyugi Narayan Mani yes u cd provide that

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[Vishnu Purana: Book 2: Chapter 6](http://kjc-sv013.kjc.uni-heidelberg.de/dcs/index.php?contents=texte&IDTextDisplay=400) has a similar verse which is slightly different but has a similar meaning.

> mārjārakukkuṭacchāgaśvavarāhavihaṃgamān / (21.1)
> poṣayannarakaṃ yāti tam eva dvijasattama // (21.2)

[Translation](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/vp/vp064.htm)

> and a Brahman who vends Lac, flesh, liquors, sesamum, or salt, or one who commits violence, fall into the hell (where matter flows, or) Púyaváha; as do they who rear cats, cocks, goats, dogs, hogs, or birds.

Comment: The difference could be due to difference in purana recensions.

Comment: @Sarvabhouma Yes it is possible.