# Is it true that people who keep dogs as pet go to hell?

Tags: sin, animals, hell

Is it true that people who keep dog as a pet goes to hell ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the source of this sloka which is prohibiting keeping pets at home?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/32586/what-is-the-source-of-this-sloka-which-is-prohibiting-keeping-pets-at-home)

Comment: You may want to reread the death of Yudhishthira in the Mahabharata.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Are dvijas allowed to touch dogs?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/54865/are-dvijas-allowed-to-touch-dogs)

Comment: Yudhistira's ascend to swarga does not explain keeping dog at home. Dog follows him but that doesn't mean it was a pet dog.

Answer (score -2):

Whether people who keep dogs as pets go to hell, it is crucial to understand that Hinduism, like many other religions, encompasses a diverse range of beliefs and interpretations. There are no specific, universally accepted Sanskrit verses in Hindu scriptures that explicitly state that pet owners, including those who keep dogs, go to hell.

In Hinduism, the idea of heaven and hell is often associated with the concept of karma, where one's actions (good or bad) have consequences that determine their future experiences. However, interpretations of what actions lead to positive or negative consequences can vary.

Like any complex belief system, cannot be reduced to a singular viewpoint on this matter. Many Hindus view animals, including dogs, with love and respect, and they may keep pets as companions without any negative spiritual implications.

If you are exploring this topic for personal or scholarly reasons, I encourage you to engage with reputable sources, consult religious scholars, and consider the diverse perspectives within Hinduism to gain a comprehensive understanding of this complex subject.